# What's the best technique for applying adhesive to the underside of ceiling joists?

Tags: drywall, ceiling

If applying adhesive while drywalling ceilings, is there a tip to applying to the underside of joists so that it doesn't drip all over the place? Also, are there places that sell applicator tips to go on the liquid nails tubes, or is there a good technique with the gun/tube that anyone's learned that keeps it on the wood, and not on you and the floor? Also, what kind of adhesive is preferred among installers?

Comment: Why are you using adhesive? That's not a common practice. Have you ever heard of drywall falling off? Anyway, you simply dispense the adhesive such that it's pressed against the wood. Angle the gun and snip the tube accordingly.

Comment: @isherwood Perhaps from reading this https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/28860/what-is-the-best-method-of-hanging-drywall-on-ceiling

Comment: For me, cheap upgrade in holding power, and I'm putting a ton of insulation on top.

Comment: Is drywall designed to hang from the upper paper? What kind of drywall is this?

Answer (score 2):

Not much to it, really. I glued and screwed ~1000 square feet of type X to 3" strapping and I don't think any "dripped off."

Standard "cut tube at an angle and hold gun at an angle so the stuff smooshes out and sticks" technique. Pretty much the same as any construction adhesive.

If you are getting a round bead that falls off you are doing it wrong - the applied bead should be about 3 times wider than it is thick, as a guesstimate. The short end of the cut tip should be in contact with the surface as you dispense, the long/pointy end should be slightly off the surface, and speed of movement and dispensing are adjusted to maintain the correct bead shape.